# Horizontal flip with UICollisionBehavior

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a small piece of an app where I need a view to move to the opposite end of the screen when tapped. Once it collides with the screen it should to a horizontal flip (transform). And this works when it moves from left to right. But when it moves from right to left it does a vertical flip and is upside down until it collides with the left side of the screen. I can't figure out why it's doing this. Here's the relevant portion of my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fish: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fishLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!

    enum Direction: CGFloat {
        case left = -1
        case right = 1

        func reversed() -> Direction {
            return Direction(rawValue: -rawValue)!
        }
    }

    var fishAnimator: UIDynamicAnimator?

    var fishDirection = Direction.right

    @objc func onFishTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: water)

        let collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [fish])
        collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self
        collisionBehavior.collisionMode = .boundaries
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

        let pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [fish], mode: .instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = 0.0000001
        pushBehavior.pushDirection = .init(dx: fishDirection.rawValue, dy: 0)
        animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)

        self.fishAnimator = animator
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollisionBehaviorDelegate {
    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {

        fishDirection = fishDirection.reversed()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.fish.transform = .init(scaleX: self.fishDirection.rawValue, y: 1)
        })
        fishLeading.constant = fish.center.x - fish.frame.size.width / 2 + fishDirection.rawValue * 2
        fishAnimator?.removeAllBehaviors()
        fishAnimator = nil
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first picture, when the fish is moving to the right it is right side up. When it is moving to the left it is upside down.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know this might be beside the point at the moment but is there any reason that you’re not doing this using SpriteKit?

Comment: I was just trying to learn more about animations. I haven't done anything with SpriteKit yet